# How to use functions in Python? is the following examplevcorrect?

Tags: python, pandas, validation

```
Q3_data = pd.read_csv('Internal_Q3_Data.csv')
Q3_df = pd.DataFrame(Q3_data)

total_rows_Q3=len(Q3_df.axes[0])

def findval(x,y):

    new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["polnb",x])

    for i in (range(6)):
        polno =df1_Summary.at[i,y]

        for i in (range(total_rows_Q3)):
            if(polno == Q3_df.at[i,'polnb']):
                value = Q3_df.at[i,x]
                new_df.at[i,'polnb'] = polno
                new_df.at[i,x] = value
            else:
                pass
    return(new_df)

#Take the copy of the Q4 dataframe

FinalData = pd.DataFrame(Q4_df)

#Replacing errors/blanks with true values 


def fillval(df):


    count = len(df)
    col = df.columns[1]

    #list(range(1,count))

    # In this case default index is exist  
    df.reset_index(inplace = True) 

    for i in range(count):
        polno = df.at[i,'polnb']
        val = df.at[i,col]

        for j in (range(total_rows)):
            if(polno == FinalData.at[j,'polnb']):
                FinalData.at[j,col] = val
            else:
                pass
    return FinalData

fillval(sexVal)
fillval(issageVal)
```

Comment: Not really; you should read tutorials specific to pandas to find the idiomatic approach. Looping through a data frame is wasteful

Comment: `read_csv()` gives `DataFrame` and you don't have to use `pd.DataFrame(Q3_data)`

Comment: most functions in pandas can do modifications on all rows and you don't have to use `for`-loop. OR you can select some rows line `df[ df[["polnb"} == 4 ]` and use function on these rows without `for`-loop